# Java console as a whole

Tags: java, exception, command-line, console, stack-trace

I get some run-time error's stacktrace on java consoler however since this stacktrace is consisting of so many lines only the most recent 45 - 50 lines of trace is seen on java console screen?

Is there any method/batch etc. to show real-time java console on a plain old windows command line console?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: use a proper ide, like netbeans/eclipse

Comment: IDE?  I am not debugging something. I need this to see what is happening background when I am trying to run a JNLP file. I may want such a dump of stacktrace from an enduser who tries to run jnlp. I can't force any enduser to install some IDEs.

Answer (score 1):

Quite funny but I experience this almost everyday.

Its occurs when there is a lot of warning, say 50 warnings, with 2 errors. And you have difficulty to see those 2 errors.

If you must use `command-line`, then the only way is by *print-screen* it while it is compiling.

Or you can switch to Eclipse or Netbeans to be able to view the full stacktrace

Comment: how can i execute the java console from command-line? I dont know its path. Or shall I ask is there such a path for an application to show java console on command-line?

Answer (score 0):

The plain old windows command console is really bad, i'd suggest either using an alternative or sticking to an IDE.
You can always pipe the results to a file with "> somefile.txt" to read it later.

Comment: I would like to pipe results of java console to somefile.txt but how and where should I write this pipelining command? I cant type anything inside java console like a cmd console.

Comment: Oh, if you are making an interactive application then that doesn't work. You could try making a method for logging the errors to disk or use a logging library. But again, your best bet is to use an IDE.